# Suppress message "your remote desktop services session has ended"

Tags: windows-server-2012, rdp

I need to suppress this window in some way on Windows Server 2012

[image]

If I have an open RDP connection to VM and another user will connect to this VM I'd like to simply close my RDP connection window without having this window. 
I tried to edit RDP file in this way and tried to change group policy. But without success.
I also found this [article](https://forum.devolutions.net/topic26908-how-to-disable-the-your-remote-desktop-services-session-has-ended-dialog-when-switching-between-vpn.aspx) which shows how to suppress for VPN but how to do this for regular RDP. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in way of disabling this message if you are using `mstsc`. This is specific to the RDP software on your client - so there might be 3rd party clients that do not present this message.

A *janky* workaround could be something like an AutoIT script that automatically closes this window as soon as it appears. Totally untested:

```
WinWait("Remote Desktop Connection","Another user connected to the remote computer")
Send("{ENTER}")
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't catch where I can run this command. In cmd or powershell I got "is not recognized as an internal or external command,"

Comment: @VasylZvarydchuk You would need to download and install https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/ and configure a script in there. If you haven't used AutoIT before, then this might not be the way to go for you.

Answer (score 1):

Add these two keys in **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon**

```
ForceAutoLogon 0
AutoAdminLogon 0
```